# Js не выводит полученные данные в leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, leafletjs

Вообщем у меня есть функция, очень простая срабатывает клик эта функция обращается на сервер возвращает данные и распихивает по нужным местам, а теперь проблема я вижу что есть данные они отображаются в нужных инпутах, однако в консоли и в popup, они не показывается там просто пустота хотя данные есть, я честно уже всё перепробовал, но так и не смог вытащить данные в popup, а это очень надо.
Вот код:

```
measoftMap.choicePvz = function (placemark) {
    // Выделяем выбранный ПВЗ в списке
    document.getElementById('pvz_list').options[placemark.number].selected = true;

    let xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><pvzlist><auth extra="'+settings.client_id+'"></auth><code>'+placemark.code+'</code></pvzlist>';
    let list_code = placemark.code;
    let list_comment = '';
    let list_address = '';
    let list_phone = '';
    let list_worktime = '';
    if (placemark.address == '') {
        ajax(api_url, {
            data: xml,
            success: function (response) {
                if (window.DOMParser) {
                    var parser = new DOMParser();
                    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
                } else {
                    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xmlDoc.async = false;
                    xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
                }

                let pvz_list = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('pvz');

                if (pvz_list.length > 0) {
                    list_address = pvz_list[0].getElementsByTagName('address')[0].innerHTML;
                    list_phone = pvz_list[0].getElementsByTagName('phone')[0].innerHTML;
                    list_worktime = pvz_list[0].getElementsByTagName('worktime')[0].innerHTML;
                    list_comment = pvz_list[0].getElementsByTagName('comment')[0].innerHTML;

                    measoftMap.savePvzData(list_code, list_address, list_phone, list_worktime);
                } else {
                    list_comment = 'Не удалось получить информацию о выбранном объекте.';
                }
            },
            error: function(jqxhr, status, errorMsg) {
                console.log(status + ": " + errorMsg);
            }
        });
    }

    console.log(list_address);
    console.log(list_phone);
    console.log(list_worktime);
    console.log(list_comment);
    let popup = L.popup().setLatLng(placemark.lat_lng).setContent('Адрес: ' + list_address + '<br>Телефон: '
        + list_phone + '<br>Часы работы: ' + list_worktime + '<hr>' + list_comment);
    popup.openOn(map);
};

measoftMap.savePvzData = function (code, address, phone, worktime) {
    // Записываем код и адрес выбранного ПВЗ
    document.getElementById('pvz_code').value = code;
    document.getElementById('pvz_address').value = address;
    document.getElementById('pvz_phone').value = phone;
    document.getElementById('pvz_worktime').value = worktime;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочтите более внимательно что такое `Promise` и как он работает!. Вы используете вывод данных в консоль не дожидаясь завершение выполнения `ajax` запроса. После выполнения `ajax` (когда данные пришли) вызывается метод `success()` в котором Вы выводите данные в инпуты. Для решения проблемы перенесите добавление данных в popup в метод `success` так:

```js
document.getElementById('pvz_list').options[placemark.number].selected = true;

    let xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><pvzlist><auth extra="'+settings.client_id+'"></auth><code>'+placemark.code+'</code></pvzlist>';
    let list_code = placemark.code;
    let list_comment = '';
    let list_address = '';
    let list_phone = '';
    let list_worktime = '';
    if (placemark.address == '') {
        ajax(api_url, {
            data: xml,
            success: function (response) {
                if (window.DOMParser) {
                    var parser = new DOMParser();
                    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
                } else {
                    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xmlDoc.async = false;
                    xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
                }

                let pvz_list = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('pvz');

                if (pvz_list.length > 0) {
                    list_address = pvz_list[0].getElementsByTagName('address')[0].innerHTML;
                    list_phone = pvz_list[0].getElementsByTagName('phone')[0].innerHTML;
                    list_worktime = pvz_list[0].getElementsByTagName('worktime')[0].innerHTML;
                    list_comment = pvz_list[0].getElementsByTagName('comment')[0].innerHTML;

                    measoftMap.savePvzData(list_code, list_address, list_phone, list_worktime);
                } else {
                    list_comment = 'Не удалось получить информацию о выбранном объекте.';
                }
                
                console.log(list_address);
                console.log(list_phone);
                console.log(list_worktime);
                console.log(list_comment);
                let popup = L.popup().setLatLng(placemark.lat_lng).setContent('Адрес: ' + list_address + '<br>Телефон: '
        + list_phone + '<br>Часы работы: ' + list_worktime + '<hr>' + list_comment);
                popup.openOn(map);
                
            },
            error: function(jqxhr, status, errorMsg) {
                console.log(status + ": " + errorMsg);
            }
        });
    }
```